# Apply Group by on latest group

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-entities

Please consider this table:

```
Organization           State          Year          Month        Value
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   O1                   NY             2017          1            1
   01                   WA             2017          1            2
   01                   SA             2017          1            3
   O1                   NY             2017          2            4
   01                   WA             2017          2            5
   01                   SA             2017          2            6
   O2                   NY             2015          9            7
   02                   WA             2015          9            8
   02                   SA             2015          9            9
   O2                   NY             2016          1            10
   02                   WA             2016          1            11
   02                   SA             2016          1            12
   O3                   NY             2017          8            13
   03                   WA             2017          8            14
   03                   SA             2017          8            15
```

I want to create this result:

```
Organization           Year          Month        Sum
------------------------------------------------------
    01                 2017            2           15
    02                 2016            1           33
    03                 2017            8           42
```

I want to group on latest `Year, Month` and calculate sum. In above sample Organization 01 has data for 2 periods but I want to group on latest period.

---

**UPDATE 1)**

```
var query = from o in MyList
            group o by new {c.Organization, c.Year , c.Month} int grp
            select new 
            { 
                grp.Key.Organization, 
                grp.Key.Year, 
                grp.Key.Month, 
                grp.Sum() 
            };
```

Comment: @MickyD, I know how to group by using linq and I used linq many years. If I know (or have idea) how to write this query be sure I didn't ask here.

Comment: what is the 2 periods in your case => `Organization 01 has data for 2 periods but I want to group on latest period.`?

Comment: @ershoaib `2017-1` and `2017-2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           

        var results = (from o in MyList
                       group o by new { o.Organization } into g
                       select new
                       {
                           Org_Id = g.Key.Organization,
                           Year = g.Select(x => x.Year)
                                   .Max(),
                           Month = g.Where(x => x.Year == g.Select(y => y.Year).Max())
                                    .Select(z => z.Month)
                                    .Max(),
                           Sum = g.Where(x => x.Month == g.Where(y => y.Year == g.Select(z => z.Year).Max())
                                                          .Select(y => y.Month)
                                                          .Max())
                                  .Select(z => z.Value)
                                  .Sum()
                       }).ToList();

        results.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Org_Id: {x.Org_Id} \t Year: {x.Year} \t Month: {x.Month} \t Sum: {x.Sum}"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**What we done in query:**

1) Group by `Organization`

2) `Org_Id`: as key of your group

3) `Year`: select `Max` year from group.

4) `Month`: select `Max` of month by selecting `Max` of year from group.

5) `Sum`: sum of value by selecting `Max` of month of `Max` of year from group.

**Output:**

[image]

**Sql for above query:**

```
SELECT [t1].[Organization] AS [Org_Id], (
    SELECT MAX([t2].[Year])
    FROM [Org] AS [t2]
    WHERE (([t1].[Organization] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[Organization] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t2].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t1].[Organization] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[Organization] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t2].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Organization] = [t2].[Organization]))))
    ) AS [Year], (
    SELECT MAX([t3].[Month])
    FROM [Org] AS [t3]
    WHERE ([t3].[Year] = ((
        SELECT MAX([t4].[Year])
        FROM [Org] AS [t4]
        WHERE (([t1].[Organization] IS NULL) AND ([t4].[Organization] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t4].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t1].[Organization] IS NULL) AND ([t4].[Organization] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t4].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Organization] = [t4].[Organization]))))
        ))) AND ((([t1].[Organization] IS NULL) AND ([t3].[Organization] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t3].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t1].[Organization] IS NULL) AND ([t3].[Organization] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t3].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Organization] = [t3].[Organization])))))
    ) AS [Month], (
    SELECT SUM([t5].[Value])
    FROM [Org] AS [t5]
    WHERE ([t5].[Month] = ((
        SELECT MAX([t6].[Month])
        FROM [Org] AS [t6]
        WHERE ([t6].[Year] = ((
            SELECT MAX([t7].[Year])
            FROM [Org] AS [t7]
            WHERE (([t1].[Organization] IS NULL) AND ([t7].[Organization] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t7].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t1].[Organization] IS NULL) AND ([t7].[Organization] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t7].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Organization] = [t7].[Organization]))))
            ))) AND ((([t1].[Organization] IS NULL) AND ([t6].[Organization] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t6].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t1].[Organization] IS NULL) AND ([t6].[Organization] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t6].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Organization] = [t6].[Organization])))))
        ))) AND ((([t1].[Organization] IS NULL) AND ([t5].[Organization] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t5].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t1].[Organization] IS NULL) AND ([t5].[Organization] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t5].[Organization] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Organization] = [t5].[Organization])))))
    ) AS [Sum]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Organization]
    FROM [Org] AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[Organization]
    ) AS [t1]
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks It works. It;s very kind of you if you could write `SQL` version.

Comment: @Arian, you could try [https://www.linqpad.net/](linqPAD) to convert it to sql. its very nice tool :)

Comment: Thanks. Could you add `SQL` version to your answer

Comment: @Arian, Currently i don't have enough time to convert it to sql bcoz i already spend much time to build up above query. you can post a new question regarding this so most likely you will get sql query from sql guys. If i get time then I'll definitely add sql query here and notify u about same :)

Comment: @Arian, upto you could try above link tool just established connection with database to tool and copy your linq query and after run then you will get sql query :)

Comment: @Arian, this article may help you => https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/generate-linq-sql-queries-with-linqpad/

Comment: @Arian, view **Sql for above query:** section in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic to get the output is wrong. What I can see from the Output grouping is done in 2 steps

**Step1**

```
Group By Organization, State, MAX(Year) AS Year, MAX(Month) AS Month, MAX(Value) As Value
```

**Step2**

```
Group By Organization, MAX(Year) AS Year, MAX(Month) AS Month, SUM(Value) As Value
```

Final Output has the **sum of max Values under each State for an Organization**.

If my assumption is correct, then you will be able to write the LINQ query for that